# Plotly horizontal bar comparizon

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, stacked-bar-chart

The chart attached is from R plotly package. Does this exist or can be done in python using the plotly package?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create diverging stacked bars in plotly-python by plotting the bars for male and female populations as separate traces, making the population values negative for the men, and then using the original values in the customdata so the populations for men display positive values.

I followed the method outlined by @empet in his answer [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/need-help-in-making-diverging-stacked-bar-charts/34023), and modified the categories and hovertemplate to fit your example.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

d = {'Age': ['0-19','20-29','30-39','40-49','50-59','60-Inf'],
     'Male': [1000,2000,4200,5000,3500,1000],
     'Female': [1000,2500,4000,4800,2000,1000],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=-df['Male'].values,
                        y=df['Age'],
                        orientation='h',
                        name='Male',
                        customdata=df['Male'],
                        hovertemplate = "Age: %{y}<br>Pop:%{customdata}<br>Gender:Male<extra></extra>"))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x= df['Female'],
                        y =df['Age'],
                        orientation='h',
                        name='Female',
                        hovertemplate="Age: %{y}<br>Pop:%{x}<br>Gender:Female<extra></extra>"))    

fig.update_layout(barmode='relative', 
                  height=400, 
                  width=700, 
                  yaxis_autorange='reversed',
                  bargap=0.01,
                  legend_orientation ='h',
                  legend_x=-0.05, legend_y=1.1
                 )
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: one small question is there a way to remove the X axis? overall super great. I appreciate your help

Comment: @Seph77 no problem - happy to help! you can hide the xaxis by using `fig.update_xaxes(visible=False)`

Comment: Sorry One more question when I use the text attribute is there a way to hide the negative  so for instance doesn't show -100 but 100  on the left side of the bar?

Comment: @Seph77 you mean that when you hover over the bars to the left of 0, you want it the hovertemplate to show positive values instead of negative values?